# How to maintain application window positions on 2nd monitor if 1st is turned off?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm running Windows 10 with 2 monitors.  The primary display is set to turn off after being idle a certain length of time.

The problem is that if the primary monitor is turned off, then when I power it back up any applications/windows that were on the 2nd monitor, have forgotten it ever existed and now appear on the first monitor, even if the 2nd monitor was never turned off.  I can actually watch all the windows jump to the primary display when it powers back up.  I have very specific and careful window positioning so this causes me some headache every time it happens.

Interestingly, Windows itself does not lose positioning of desktop icons.  Those that were on the 2nd display before, are still on the 2nd display.

Is there any way to get application window positions on the 2nd display, to survive power down of the primary display?  Or am I stuck letting the primary monitor go to "sleep" but not actually turning off?

Comment: In an amusing twist I'm trying to solve the oposite problem. All my windows end up on one monitor and never go back to their original locations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[Nirsoft MultiMonitor Tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)** app.
You can see sleeping display via app's Display Preview. And move your app's windows between displays.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you power off a monitor, rather than drop it to some kind of power save mode, then as far as the computer is concerned you disconnected it.

At this point, your other screen is assigned to be primary & all windows will be moved to it.

When you power up your 'real' primary… then youc omputer once again sees it as primary & moves all your windows back to it - because they are all already on 'primary' & 'primary' just changed.

The fix is to not power it off. Make it sleep/power save.

Comment: So even though the secondary monitor is still on and I'm looking at the windows on it, powering back up the primary monitor will "steal" all the windows??  That seems nuts.

Comment: It has to follow one logic or another. The alternative would be to leave windows open on the screen you disconnected.

Comment: I'm afraid you are missing the problem.  The secondary monitor is on, and never turns off.  The windows are all there.  There is no reason for them to go anywhere.  But when the primary is turned off and back on, the windows *jump* from the secondary (which again, was never off) to the primary.

Comment: You're not reading my answer. The "Primary" changes when your real primary is switched off - the other becomes primary & all windows are moved to it. Then when it's reconnected, the real primary becomes primary again… & windows are again moved to the primary.

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't catch that nuance.  Thanks for clarifying.  Although that still doesn't make sense.  The windows are on the secondary.  Primary switches off, the windows are now on the primary (same monitor).  Original primary switches back on, the windows should now be on the secondary (same monitor).  Makes absolutely no sense for them to move like they do.  None of the original primary's windows move to the secondary, when the primary switches off so... this just seems weird.